# Artificial tick labels for seaborn heatmaps

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, seaborn

I have a seaborn heatmap that looks like this:

[image]

...generated from a pandas dataframe of randomly generated values a piece of which looks like this:

[image]

The values along the y axis are all in the range [0,1], and the ones on the x axis in the range [0,2*pi], and I just want some short floats at regular intervals for my tick labels, but I can only seem to get values that are in my dataframe. When I try specifying the values I want, it doesn't put them in the right place, as seen in the plot above. He's my code right now. How can I get the axis labels that I tried specifying with xticks and yticks in this code in the correct places (which would be evenly spaced along the axes)?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata

sns.set_style("darkgrid")
PHI, COSTH = np.meshgrid(phis, cos_thetas)
THICK = griddata(phis, cos_thetas, thicknesses, PHI, COSTH, interp='linear')

thick_df = pd.DataFrame(THICK, columns=phis, index=cos_thetas)
thick_df = thick_df.sort_index(axis=0, ascending=False)
thick_df = thick_df.sort_index(axis=1)

cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(start=1.6, light=0.8, as_cmap=True, reverse=True)

yticks = np.array([0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0])

xticks = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])

g = sns.heatmap(thick_df, linewidth=0, xticklabels=xticks, yticklabels=yticks, square=True, cmap=cmap)

plt.show(g)
```

Comment: Note that I've also tried stuff alone the lines of `xticks = [str(x) if i % 10 == 0 else '' for i,x in enumerate(xticks)]` but the values are still long, random floats.

Comment: If you only want e.g. a tick label every five fields you could try making an array with four empty strings inbetween each value. It would make sense that your tick arrays needs to have as many elements as your heatmap has rows/columns. Also I'd use strings instead of numbers.

Comment: But this is what my comment above accomplishes and the problem is that every five values or whatever is still a long, nasty float. Do you mean use that to specify a location and then put a separate string value there? Can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read that correctly. Instead of `str(x)` try this: `'{:.2f}'.format(x)` for floats with 2 decimal positions.

Comment: What's `phis`, `cos_thetas`, `thicknesses` in your code above?

Comment: Phis and cos_thetas are randomly generated points on a spherical surface. Thicknesses is calculated from something super non-trivial so I didn't think I could do a true mwe here. Sorry!

Comment: In this case next time you should replace it with dummy data that would serve the same purposes, like `phis = 2*math.pi * np.random.rand(24)` (that's what I used)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's something that should do what you want:

```
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(start=1.6, light=0.8, as_cmap=True, reverse=True)

yticks = np.linspace(0,1,6)

x_end = 6
xticks = np.arange(x_end+1)

ax = sns.heatmap(thick_df, linewidth=0, xticklabels=xticks, yticklabels=yticks[::-1], square=True, cmap=cmap)

ax.set_xticks(xticks*ax.get_xlim()[1]/(2*math.pi))
ax.set_yticks(yticks*ax.get_ylim()[1])

plt.show()
```

[image: Seaborn heatmap]

You could pass `['{:,.2f}'.format(x) for x in xticks]` instead of xticks to get a float with 2 decimals.

Note that I'm reversing the yticklabels because that's what seaborn does: see [matrix.py#L138](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/14078fe9b4bb0b6b6fc957d6dfa0d18dc0adbbef/seaborn/matrix.py#L138).

Seaborn calculates the tick positions around the same place (e.g.: [#L148](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/14078fe9b4bb0b6b6fc957d6dfa0d18dc0adbbef/seaborn/matrix.py#L148)), for you that amounts to:

```
# thick_df.T.shape[0] = thick_df.shape[1]
xticks: np.arange(0, thick_df.T.shape[0], 1) + .5
yticks: np.arange(0, thick_df.T.shape[1], 1) + .5
```